# How to get rid the inline style using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to remove these two inline style beside the .dropdwon menu, I tried the remove attribute [ **jQuery('.dropdown-menu').removeAttr('style');** ] unfortunately it doesn't remove the inline style. Every time I hover the nav the inline style change to **display block** and when it hover out the inline style is set to **display:none**

```
<ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu" style="display: none;">
<ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu" style="display: block;">
```

Here's my code. I'm trying to remove this on size 767 or mediaquery max-width(767)

```
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    var width = jQuery(window).width();
    if( width < 767 ) {
      jQuery('.dropdown-menu').removeAttr("style");
    }
});

jQuery(document).resize(function() {
    var width = jQuery(document).width();
    if( width < 767 ) {
      jQuery('.dropdown-menu').removeAttr("style");
    }
});
```

please see the two attached image for better visualization

When I hover the nav(About) the subpage show(ul.dropdown-menu) and the inline style will set to **display block**
[image]

When I hover out the nav(About) the subpage (ul.dropdown-menu) inline style will set to **display none**
[image]

**Please help me get rid these two inline style the style="display:none"; and style="display:block";**

Comment: May i ask what you want to get rid of them? , but if you really want to remove it, try `$('.dropdown-menu').css("display","")`

Comment: use $('element').css('display','none'); where you want

Comment: Functions like `.hide()` and `.show()` work by adding inline styles. Are you using them in your script?

Comment: @carsten I want to get rid the inline style beside ul.dropdown-menu, here is the current html <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu" style="display: none;">. What I want to happen is like this <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu"> no inline style beside the class dropdwon-menu

Comment: Have you tried forcing it in CSS ? And use CSS media queries instead.

Comment: Your code basically works.... for a visual example: https://jsfiddle.net/10e1rehu/ . Are you getting any console errors? You also have a leading space in your `ul` before the class name eg: `<ul class=" dropdown-menu">` , that could be a problem, though it works in my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/10e1rehu/1/.

Comment: @j-printemps I tried it just now by using css the problem is the subpage won't open after I set to display: none !important. What I want to achieve is to remove the inline style display: none and display block. I don't want my sub pages in mobile view is set to to hover because it is bad ux. the subpages should only show when clicking the navigation in mobile view

Comment: @JonP about the space inside the class I notice that too. I think it is default that there is a space because I'm using Bootstrap Navwalker. my website is built in bootstrap and i converted it to wordpress and to be able to run the bootstrap navbar in wordpress I use Navwalker

Answer (score 4):

Try with [`show()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi1gtuu_pvUAhVJOI8KHWZGDx0QFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fshow%2F&usg=AFQjCNHOVPL0N8oUECD1DYHnl6J3lfq6qA&sig2=T-6BKKV0XFx6TmD4JhYi2w)

`jQuery('.dropdown-menu').show()`

**or** [`css()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj6gu_b_pvUAhXCto8KHVgnC6IQFgg2MAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fcss%2F&usg=AFQjCNGpX40YDkFD6xGrnN6xrgMbkgkIvQ&sig2=LBglIRVrhzFh7RlcNnKsAA)

`jQuery('.dropdown-menu').css('display','block')`

Drag the output window of the fiddle .They will show the menu on resize

[**Demo Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9n61xmr4/)

Comment: nope. I don't want to show it. I want to totally get rid the inline styles beside the .dropdown-menu because in mobile view it is bad habbit in ux that the subpage are hovering. the sub page should show only when clicking the nav parent (example: when I click the about that's the time the sub page will appear)

Answer (score 2):

There is a JavaScript somewhere that is adding those styles. I guess you are using some framework or template you found in the Internet. Now you either have to remove the not-needed code that adds the styles (recommended!) or bind over it to be removed each time, something like what you have written but in different event:

```
jQuery('.dropdown-menu').hover(function() {
      jQuery('.dropdown-menu').removeAttr("style");
}, function() {
      jQuery('.dropdown-menu').removeAttr("style");
});
```

Ensuring this is after the piece of code that does the style adding at first place.

Or you can try totally removing the behaviour for the menu and write  your own:

```
jQuery('.dropdown-menu').unbind();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `click` instead of `hover` for mobile, and `display: none;` by default, set in CSS. Then add a media queries for PC (here > 767px) to force `display: block;`. The good thing is that you limit the use of JS.

This is a working example of what can be done.

**EDIT**

I updated the snippet with an example which is, I think, closer to your code.

```js
$('.menu-item').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.menu-item .dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}

.menu-item.active .dropdown-menu {
  display: block !important;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  .menu-item .dropdown-menu {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul role="menu" class="menu">
 <li class="menu-item">Menu 1</li>
 <li class="menu-item">
    Menu 2
  <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu" style="display: none;">
    <li>Submenu 1</li>
    <li>Submenu 2</li>
    <li>Submenu 3</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to append at the end of your main css file a rule-set declaration on `.dropdown-menu` selector with the property `display:none` for media-query < 767:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 766px) {
    .dropdown-menu {
        display:none;
    }
}
```